# No relay IP at https://explorer.mainnet.cardano.org/relays/topology.json after more than 2 weeks

Tags: stake-pool

I have to say, that i have already done 1 SPO about month ago, and all was fine.
Today i have struggling with another one that i have to set up.
All looks like fine, but i can't see mine realay IP on https://explorer.mainnet.cardano.org/relays/topology.json and no metter what i do.. (First SPO relay was there really quick)

So please help me to figure out what is wrong now..

ScreenShots (let me know if need any more)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> All looks like fine, but i can't see mine realay IP on https://explorer.mainnet.cardano.org/relays/topology.json and no metter what i do

That URL only fetches relays that are registered as part of pool registration and can be reached publicly - besides, it is refreshed to catch peers publicly twice a week (might have changed since). So if you have modified your pool registration details to include your new relay, and your pool is reachable publicly - you might want to wait for a few days before trying to query that URL.

Your outbound topology.json file or subscription to topology Updater is irrelevant to be listed on the mentioned link.

Comment: RdLrT thansk for anwser. I'm a little be confused, so it's no metter if my relay ip is not there? It's still will work correctly and produce blocks?

I ask it, cose all tutorials says that i have to be in that list, before continue set up SPO. In another words if you not in that list, your SPO will not produce block or will produce but no rewards will be generated..

P.S. It's new SPO with 1 bp and 1 relay. It's not extend currenct SPO with another relay.

Comment: Btw that file last update was: last-modified: Thu, 22 Sep 2022 20:29:47 GMT or last-modified: Thu, 01 Sep 2022 14:00:21 GMT it's depends what file loaded (cose there is 2 different files). It's obviously is something wrong with that..

Comment: You need incoming peers (be it via topologyUpdater or other manual peering arrangements with different SPOs) - but the link you're looking at isn't a source of truth, and the peers that appear in the list are as mentioned in the reply